# What's causing this runtime error and how can I rectify it?

Tags: c++, runtime-error, sdl-2, glew

The following error occurred during runtime:

> The procedure entry point `_ZSt24__throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz` could not be located in the dynamic link library "test.exe".

I used a C++ demangler to find out which function is causing the entry point error.
The function is: `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)`

I am linking to the following libraries:

- SDL2 (Dynamic, compiled from source by myself, same version of GCC that I'm using for my project (4.9.3)).
- GLEW (Added source to project)

I compiled SDL2 from source with the same version of GCC that I use in my project because I thought that the pre-built version I was using had somehow caused a conflict in the different C++ Standard Libraries. I then attempted to link dynamically to this build, but the exact same runtime error persisted.

Compilation & Linking Script Log (Compiled via a Windows BATCH script):

```
C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\src\camera.o
C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\src\datatranslation.o
C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\src\glew.o
C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\src\light.o
C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\src\listeners.o
C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\src\matrix.o
C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\src\mesh.o
C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\src\model_loader.o
C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\src\object.o
C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\src\quaternion.o
C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\src\shader.o
C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\src\stb_image.o
C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\src\test.o
C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\src\texture.o
C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\src\timekeeper.o
C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\src\utility.o
C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\src\vector.o
C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\src\window.o
C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\src\world.o
       19 file(s) moved.
Compilation Completed, ".o" files are in "C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\cpl\Thu 08.25.2016"
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-4.9.3/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC)
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-LC:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\lib' '-LC:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\Lua\5.3.2\lib' '-o' 'oculargame-test.exe' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/collect2.exe -plugin c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/liblto_plugin-0.dll -plugin-opt=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\Harrand\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUhcnbk.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -Bdynamic -u ___register_frame_info -u ___deregister_frame_info -o oculargame-test.exe c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../crt2.o c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/crtbegin.o -LC:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\lib -LC:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\Lua\5.3.2\lib -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3 -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/lib -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../.. camera.o datatranslation.o glew.o light.o listeners.o matrix.o mesh.o model_loader.o object.o quaternion.o shader.o stb_image.o test.o texture.o timekeeper.o utility.o vector.o window.o world.o -lOpenGL32 -lSDL2 -lSDL2main C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\res\exe\ocular.res -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/crtend.o
        1 file(s) moved.
Linking Completed, "oculargame-test.exe" is in "C:\Users\Harrand\Desktop\Ocular GEng\cpl\Thu 08.25.2016\lnk"
```

Only error message printed during runtime is the title of this question. I am linking to the following libs:

- libSDL2.a (DLL implib for SDL2)
- libSDL2main.a

I am only linking to the dynamic link library libSDL2.dll. My previous suspicion was that because SDL2 was pre-built before I compiled it myself, there was a conflict in the compiler versions. However, I now know that this isn't the case. Could this error be somehow caused by the fact that I added the GLEW source code to my project?

Comment: I have the same problem and from what i found it is because some of the libs were compiled with different version of compiler and linked to different version of standard C++ libs than what you're using to compile your own app. You must either install the same compiler as which was used for those libs, or download their sources and compile them with your current compiler. When you try it, tell me if it worked.

Comment: @Youda008 I understand what you said, and I believe you are right. However, when the problem first arose, the error did not arise every time I attempted to execute the program; sometimes it ran without an error at all, when I didn't make any changes! In addition, you can check my most recent edit to see a realisation I made. I am once again lost, and if you have information to offer, I would welcome it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial suspicion was not correct but on the right tracks: The version of MinGW which I intended to use was NOT the same as the version of MinGW that I installed into the system path long ago. The effect of this was that the dependency that an executable has on the G++ DLLs was, by default, targeting the DLLs of the version of MinGW which I had installed; the wrong version. This caused the runtime error.

This problem was resolved by replacing:

```
"C:\MinGW\bin\g++"*.o -L%libdir% -L"%scriptdir%\Lua\5.3.2\lib" -lOpenGL32 -lSDL2 -lSDL2main "%scriptdir%\res\exe\ocular.res" -o "oculargame-test.exe"
```

with

```
"C:\MinGW\bin\g++" -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ *.o -L%libdir% -L"%scriptdir%\Lua\5.3.2\lib" -lOpenGL32 -lSDL2 -lSDL2main "%scriptdir%\res\exe\ocular.res" -o "oculargame-test.exe"
```

I added the flags `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` to the command so that the MinGW version that I wanted to use (In "C:\MinGW\bin") would statically link the dependencies into the executable so that the conflict would not occur. I hope this helps others with similarly tricky issues.