# Linker Errors from SDL2 in my project

Tags: c++, opengl, linker-errors, sdl-2

I used CMake and Code::Blocks to build SDL2 from source, and attempted to link my own project source to the following static libraries:

```
libSDL2.a
libSDL2main.a
OpenGL32.lib
```

These three libraries are contained within the directory known as `%libdir%` (I'm using Batch for the command).

I obtained libSDL2 and libSDL2main from the Code::Blocks build. I obtained OpenGL32 from my Windows directory, although I found it long ago so I am unable to recall the exact location. I used the following command:

```
g++ *.o -L%libDir% -lOpenGL32 -lSDL2main -lSDL -o "output.exe"
```

Below is the log, how can I rectify these errors?:

```
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windows.c.obj): In function `WIN_CoInitialize':
sdlsrc/core/windows/SDL_windows.c:73: undefined reference to `CoInitializeEx@8'
sdlsrc/core/windows/SDL_windows.c:75: undefined reference to `CoInitializeEx@8'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windows.c.obj): In function `WIN_CoUninitialize':
sdlsrc/core/windows/SDL_windows.c:92: undefined reference to `CoUninitialize@0'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_SetupAPI':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:617: undefined reference to `ImmGetIMEFileNameA@12'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:630: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:633: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_GetId':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:551: undefined reference to `ImmGetIMEFileNameA@12'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:566: undefined reference to `GetFileVersionInfoSizeA@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:570: undefined reference to `GetFileVersionInfoA@16'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:571: undefined reference to `VerQueryValueA@16'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `UIElementSink_QueryInterface@12':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1013: undefined reference to `IID_IUnknown'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IPPASink_QueryInterface@12':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1119: undefined reference to `IID_IUnknown'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `UILess_GetCandidateList':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:984: undefined reference to `SysFreeString@4'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_ClearComposition':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:683: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:687: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:691: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:692: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:689: undefined reference to `ImmSetCompositionStringW@24'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_Disable':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:364: undefined reference to `ImmAssociateContext@8'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `UIElementSink_BeginUIElement@12':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1051: undefined reference to `SysFreeString@4'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `UIElementSink_UpdateUIElement@8':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1078: undefined reference to `SysFreeString@4'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_Init':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:309: undefined reference to `CoCreateInstance@20'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:323: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:324: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `UILess_SetupSinks':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1192: undefined reference to `CoCreateInstance@20'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_ClearComposition':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:683: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:687: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:691: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:692: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:689: undefined reference to `ImmSetCompositionStringW@24'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_GetId':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:551: undefined reference to `ImmGetIMEFileNameA@12'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:566: undefined reference to `GetFileVersionInfoSizeA@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:570: undefined reference to `GetFileVersionInfoA@16'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_GetReadingString':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:423: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:498: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_GetId':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:571: undefined reference to `VerQueryValueA@16'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_Quit':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:378: undefined reference to `ImmAssociateContext@8'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_Enable':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:349: undefined reference to `ImmAssociateContext@8'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_ClearComposition':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:683: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:687: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:691: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:692: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:689: undefined reference to `ImmSetCompositionStringW@24'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_Disable':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:364: undefined reference to `ImmAssociateContext@8'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `WIN_SetTextInputRect':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:202: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:209: undefined reference to `ImmSetCompositionWindow@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:210: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_HandleMessage':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:852: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_GetCompositionString':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:699: undefined reference to `ImmGetCompositionStringW@16'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:704: undefined reference to `ImmGetCompositionStringW@16'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_HandleMessage':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:890: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_ClearComposition':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:683: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:687: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:691: undefined reference to `ImmNotifyIME@16'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:692: undefined reference to `ImmReleaseContext@8'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_HandleMessage':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:885: undefined reference to `ImmGetContext@4'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_GetCandidateList':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:767: undefined reference to `ImmGetCandidateListW@16'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_GetCompositionString':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:699: undefined reference to `ImmGetCompositionStringW@16'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:704: undefined reference to `ImmGetCompositionStringW@16'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_ClearComposition':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:689: undefined reference to `ImmSetCompositionStringW@24'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_GetCandidateList':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:771: undefined reference to `ImmGetCandidateListW@16'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_Render':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1520: undefined reference to `CreateCompatibleDC@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1525: undefined reference to `DeleteDC@4'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_RenderCandidateList':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1394: undefined reference to `CreatePen@12'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1395: undefined reference to `CreateSolidBrush@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1396: undefined reference to `CreatePen@12'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1397: undefined reference to `CreateSolidBrush@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1398: undefined reference to `CreatePen@12'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1399: undefined reference to `CreateSolidBrush@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1400: undefined reference to `CreateFontW@56'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1402: undefined reference to `SetBkMode@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1403: undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1410: undefined reference to `GetTextExtentPoint32W@16'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `StartDrawToBitmap':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1259: undefined reference to `CreateDIBSection@24'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1261: undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_RenderCandidateList':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1458: undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1459: undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `DrawRect':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1285: undefined reference to `Rectangle@20'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_RenderCandidateList':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1462: undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1463: undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1464: undefined reference to `SetTextColor@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1465: undefined reference to `SetBkMode@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1496: undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1497: undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1498: undefined reference to `SetTextColor@8'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `DrawRect':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1285: undefined reference to `Rectangle@20'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_RenderCandidateList':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1502: undefined reference to `ExtTextOutW@32'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1491: undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `StopDrawToBitmap':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1270: undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj): In function `IME_RenderCandidateList':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1506: undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1507: undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1508: undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1509: undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowskeyboard.c.obj):sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowskeyboard.c:1510: more undefined references to `DeleteObject@4' follow
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowsmessagebox.c.obj): In function `WIN_ShowMessageBox':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmessagebox.c:396: undefined reference to `CreateCompatibleDC@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmessagebox.c:405: undefined reference to `CreateFontIndirectW@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmessagebox.c:409: undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmessagebox.c:413: undefined reference to `GetTextMetricsW@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmessagebox.c:428: undefined reference to `DeleteDC@4'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowsmessagebox.c.obj): In function `CreateDialogData':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmessagebox.c:301: undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowsmouse.c.obj): In function `WIN_CreateCursor':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmouse.c:129: undefined reference to `CreateDIBSection@24'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmouse.c:130: undefined reference to `CreateBitmap@20'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmouse.c:140: undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmouse.c:141: undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowsshape.c.obj): In function `CombineRectRegions':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsshape.c:53: undefined reference to `CreateRectRgn@16'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsshape.c:55: undefined reference to `CombineRgn@16'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsshape.c:56: undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowswindow.c.obj): In function `WIN_SetWindowGammaRamp':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowswindow.c:606: undefined reference to `CreateDCW@16'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowswindow.c:608: undefined reference to `SetDeviceGammaRamp@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowswindow.c:612: undefined reference to `DeleteDC@4'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowswindow.c.obj): In function `WIN_GetWindowGammaRamp':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowswindow.c:625: undefined reference to `CreateDCW@16'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowswindow.c:627: undefined reference to `GetDeviceGammaRamp@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowswindow.c:631: undefined reference to `DeleteDC@4'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.c.obj): In function `SDL_SetSystemTimerResolution':
sdlsrc/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:57: undefined reference to `timeBeginPeriod@4'
sdlsrc/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:51: undefined reference to `timeEndPeriod@4'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.c.obj): In function `SDL_TicksInit':
sdlsrc/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:102: undefined reference to `timeGetTime@0'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.c.obj): In function `SDL_SetSystemTimerResolution':
sdlsrc/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:51: undefined reference to `timeEndPeriod@4'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.c.obj): In function `SDL_GetTicks_REAL':
sdlsrc/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:141: undefined reference to `timeGetTime@0'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.c.obj): In function `SDL_TicksInit':
sdlsrc/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:102: undefined reference to `timeGetTime@0'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.c.obj): In function `SDL_GetTicks_REAL':
sdlsrc/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:141: undefined reference to `timeGetTime@0'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_systimer.c.obj): In function `SDL_TicksInit':
sdlsrc/timer/windows/SDL_systimer.c:102: undefined reference to `timeGetTime@0'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_mmjoystick.c.obj): In function `SDL_SYS_JoystickInit':
sdlsrc/joystick/windows/SDL_mmjoystick.c:166: undefined reference to `joyGetNumDevs@0'
sdlsrc/joystick/windows/SDL_mmjoystick.c:171: undefined reference to `joyGetPosEx@8'
sdlsrc/joystick/windows/SDL_mmjoystick.c:173: undefined reference to `joyGetDevCapsA@12'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_mmjoystick.c.obj): In function `SDL_SYS_JoystickUpdate':
sdlsrc/joystick/windows/SDL_mmjoystick.c:326: undefined reference to `joyGetPosEx@8'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_winmm.c.obj): In function `WINMM_CloseDevice':
sdlsrc/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:170: undefined reference to `waveOutUnprepareHeader@12'
sdlsrc/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:170: undefined reference to `waveOutUnprepareHeader@12'
sdlsrc/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:182: undefined reference to `waveInClose@4'
sdlsrc/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:187: undefined reference to `waveOutClose@4'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_winmm.c.obj): In function `WINMM_PlayDevice':
sdlsrc/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:131: undefined reference to `waveOutWrite@12'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_winmm.c.obj): In function `SetMMerror':
sdlsrc/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:106: undefined reference to `waveOutGetErrorTextW@12'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_winmm.c.obj): In function `WINMM_OpenDevice':
sdlsrc/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:285: undefined reference to `waveOutOpen@24'
sdlsrc/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:331: undefined reference to `waveOutPrepareHeader@12'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_winmm.c.obj): In function `PrepWaveFormat':
sdlsrc/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:216: undefined reference to `waveOutOpen@24'
sdlsrc/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:214: undefined reference to `waveInOpen@24'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_winmm.c.obj): In function `WINMM_OpenDevice':
sdlsrc/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:281: undefined reference to `waveInOpen@24'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_winmm.c.obj): In function `DetectWaveInDevs':
sdlsrc/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:57: undefined reference to `waveInGetNumDevs@0'
sdlsrc/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:57: undefined reference to `waveInGetDevCapsW@12'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_winmm.c.obj): In function `DetectWaveOutDevs':
sdlsrc/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:56: undefined reference to `waveOutGetNumDevs@0'
sdlsrc/audio/winmm/SDL_winmm.c:56: undefined reference to `waveOutGetDevCapsW@12'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowsframebuffer.c.obj): In function `WIN_CreateWindowFramebuffer':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsframebuffer.c:36: undefined reference to `DeleteDC@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsframebuffer.c:39: undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsframebuffer.c:53: undefined reference to `CreateCompatibleBitmap@12'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsframebuffer.c:54: undefined reference to `GetDIBits@28'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsframebuffer.c:55: undefined reference to `GetDIBits@28'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsframebuffer.c:56: undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsframebuffer.c:86: undefined reference to `CreateCompatibleDC@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsframebuffer.c:87: undefined reference to `CreateDIBSection@24'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsframebuffer.c:93: undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowsframebuffer.c.obj): In function `WIN_UpdateWindowFramebuffer':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsframebuffer.c:102: undefined reference to `BitBlt@36'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowsframebuffer.c.obj): In function `WIN_DestroyWindowFramebuffer':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsframebuffer.c:116: undefined reference to `DeleteDC@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsframebuffer.c:120: undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowsmodes.c.obj): In function `WIN_GetDisplayMode':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:108: undefined reference to `CreateDCW@16'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:112: undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:113: undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:153: undefined reference to `CreateCompatibleBitmap@12'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:154: undefined reference to `GetDIBits@28'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:155: undefined reference to `GetDIBits@28'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:156: undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:157: undefined reference to `DeleteDC@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:137: undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:138: undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:145: undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:144: undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:108: undefined reference to `CreateDCW@16'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:112: undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:113: undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:153: undefined reference to `CreateCompatibleBitmap@12'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:154: undefined reference to `GetDIBits@28'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:155: undefined reference to `GetDIBits@28'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:156: undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:157: undefined reference to `DeleteDC@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:137: undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:138: undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:145: undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsmodes.c:144: undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowsopengl.c.obj): In function `WIN_GL_ChoosePixelFormatARB':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsopengl.c:446: undefined reference to `ChoosePixelFormat@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsopengl.c:446: undefined reference to `SetPixelFormat@12'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowsopengl.c.obj): In function `WIN_GL_ChoosePixelFormat':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsopengl.c:208: undefined reference to `DescribePixelFormat@16'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsopengl.c:212: undefined reference to `DescribePixelFormat@16'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowsopengl.c.obj): In function `WIN_GL_SetupWindowInternal':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsopengl.c:579: undefined reference to `SetPixelFormat@12'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowsopengl.c.obj): In function `WIN_GL_InitExtensions':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsopengl.c:360: undefined reference to `ChoosePixelFormat@8'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsopengl.c:360: undefined reference to `SetPixelFormat@12'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowsopengl.c.obj): In function `WIN_GL_SwapWindow':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsopengl.c:774: undefined reference to `SwapBuffers@4'
projectdir\lib/libSDL2.a(SDL_windowsopengl.c.obj): In function `WIN_GL_SetPixelFormatFrom':
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsopengl.c:795: undefined reference to `GetPixelFormat@4'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsopengl.c:798: undefined reference to `DescribePixelFormat@16'
sdlsrc/video/windows/SDL_windowsopengl.c:801: undefined reference to `SetPixelFormat@12'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I suspected that perhaps I need to provide windows libraries (I'm using windows 10)? If that is the case, which libraries do I need and where can I find them? Why did this issue not occur when I used a pre-built version of SDL2?

Comment: Do you really need `OpenGL32.lib`? Probably you want opengl functions loader (like glew). Considering build try `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2` linking flags and add `-I${SDL2IncludeDir}` <- capital i there.

Comment: @mlkn I added GLEW to my project. OpenGL32 is necessary, is it not? mingw32 will not contain OpenGL functions? Surely the -I flag is not necessary either, as the compilation is fine, I have all the .o files I need; it's a linker error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you link with static SDL, you need to manually pull all libraries it uses:

```
imagehlp dinput8 dxguid dxerr8 user32 gdi32 winmm imm32 ole32
oleaut32 shell32 version uuid
```

Or just use dynamic SDL2.

Comment: Thank you. I realised that there was no advantage in linking statically to SDL2 in my scenario. Dynamic SDL2 is far easier and didn't require linking to any of the windows libraries that SDL2 uses.

Answer (score 0):

`SDL2main` goes **before** `SDL2`. Linking order matters.

---

Also, I'm sorry, but I must say that this

> I obtained libSDL2 and libSDL2main from the Code::Blocks build. I obtained OpenGL32 from my Windows directory

sounds weird. You shouldn't do it like this.

I'm not sure what you mean by *"Code::Blocks build"*, but you should obtain SDL libs as well as includes for it from http://libsdl.org/download-2.0.php and nowhere else. It's called *"MinGW build"*.

OpenGL, on the other hand, shouldn't be obtained anywhere. It should already be a part of your compiler package. You can link it with just `-lOpenGL32`.

Comment: I didn't use the MinGW build because it caused the following incompatibility from a previous issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945744/the-procedure-entry-point-zst24-throw-out-of-range-fmtpkcz-could-not-be-locate
My solution to this was to build the source of SDL2 with my compiler so that the mismatch would be solved (It appears to be an incompatible version of native C++ headers between SDL2 and my project), hence why I built it myself. Edit: I did not, however, know that sdl2main was to be linked first. Thank you.

Comment: @Harrand What compiler do you use? The one that comes with CodeBlocks is usually outdated. If you have it, you should install the last mingw-w64.

Comment: I didn't use the one which came with CodeBlocks. I use the same version of GCC which I'm using for my project; you can tell CodeBlocks to use a compiler of your choice.

Comment: *"you can tell CodeBlocks to use a compiler of your choice"* - I know, otherwise I wouldn't suggest you to update it. | *"I use the same version of GCC"* - I mean exactly what compiler. I assume that's some version of mingw, right? Which one? | Also, have you used correct libs? MinGW build contains libs for both i686 and x86_64. You need to use i686 if you're compiling for x32, otherwise you will get errors.