# Undefined reference to SDL functions using Code::Blocks

Tags: c, sdl, codeblocks, static-linking

There are quite a few similar topics on SO regarding this but I have exhausted all the suggestions on 15 similar threads.

Upon running tutorial code utilizing the SDL library, the IDE is complaining of "undefined reference" to all functions pertaining to SDL.

**Situation**

Architecture: 64 bit

IDE: CodeBlocks 16.01

Compiler: GNU GCC

**What I have tried to do**

1) I told the compiler to find header under directory:
.....\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2 using relative paths

I did NOT select \include NOR did I select .....\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2

2) I told compiler to find library files under directory:
.....\i686-w64-mingw32\lib using relative paths

I did NOT select ....\lib NOR did I select .....\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib

3) When linking the libraries, I included four libraries under the directory 
....\i686-w64-mingw32\lib and NOT the other directories as mentioned above.

4) The order in which the libraries were linked are as follows:

SDL2main.lib

SDL2.lib

SDL2test.lib

5) I ensured that the properties of main.c were such that compile file was checked, link file was checked, and the belongs in targets  debug and release were both checked.

**Build log:**

> -------------- Build: Debug in Snake Game (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------
>
> mingw32-g++.exe
>   -L......\Downloads\SDL2-devel-2.0.4-mingw\SDL2-2.0.4\i686-w64-mingw32\lib
>   -o "bin\Debug\Snake Game.exe" obj\Debug\main.o   -lmingw32 ......\Downloads\SDL2-devel-2.0.4-mingw\SDL2-2.0.4\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libSDL2main.a
>   ......\Downloads\SDL2-devel-2.0.4-mingw\SDL2-2.0.4\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libSDL2.a
>   obj\Debug\main.o: In function `SDL_main':
>   C:/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/main.c:9: undefined
>   reference to`SDL_WM_SetCaption'

The log goes on and on with undefined references.

Can anybody guide me in solving this linking problem?

Comment: What compiler? MinGW?

Comment: please include the full link trace provided by code::blocks: command and output.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat GNU GCC

Comment: What OS then? Windows?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes

Comment: Then you're probably using MinGW, which is a windows port of GCC. See if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `SDL_WM_SetCaption` in SDL2. Your code is likely to be using older SDL 1.2. Either use correct library or modify your code e.g following https://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide

Comment: I made the following changes: I copied in SDL2 code as you have mentioned.

Comment: I am now getting an error "SDL.h: No such file or directory" which has now become a compiler search problem. I have left the directories the same. I included the directories as both relative and non-relative. I have tried to change #include <SDL.h> to #include "SDL.h". No luck

Comment: I'm not going to do a guesswork, not without source and compile line. Maybe you should add source code of minimal program you having errors with to the question. Or just take any SDL2 example to start with. If your test program uses `SDL_WM_SetCaption` - clearly it is not for SDL2 and you should not follow that tutorial of yours (or switch to SDL1, which I don't recommend). It is very likely you'll hit a very different sort of [linking errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110217/linker-errors-from-sdl2-in-my-project); it would be much simpler to use dynamic libraries for a beginner.

Comment: I have started in an absolute clean slate: My only source code is:

Comment: #include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{

}

Comment: Build log is: mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g -Wall -IC:\mingw_dev_lib\include -c "C:\Users\dejanp\Documents\C_C++ Code\Snake Game\main.c" -o obj\Debug\main.o

Comment: I cannot even change or add this to the original question because it is a new error - it is not even recognising the SDL include

Comment: I have even cross checked with this very good tutorial but with no luck: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/codeblocks/index.php

Comment: 1. It is highly unrecommended to post commentchains with code (unless you want to upset someone). 2. `#include <SDL.h>`, but there is no `SDL.h` in `C:\mingw_dev_lib\include`. There is a **directory** SDL2 there, which contains `SDL.h`. So correct one is either `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` or `-IC:\mingw_dev_lib\include\SDL2` compiler flag (and linked tutorial uses latter - bad crosschecking).

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I now referenced \mingw_dev_lib\include\SDL2 and it seems to begin to compile. I am now getting an error after startup of console saying "The program can't start because SDL2.dll is missing from your computer". All the tutorials dont make mention of this? I tried adding it anyway with no luck. We're getting closer...

Comment: Quote from the tutorial you've linked "Go find the SDL 2 folder you extracted and from the bin folder inside copy SDL2.dll and put it either where your executable will run, or inside of the system directory. C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32 is the 32bit windows system directory and C:\Windows\SysWOW64 is the 64bit system directory of 32bit applications". Please, this is getting ridiculous :-(

Comment: It works! I copied the *wrong dll - I didnt use the correct dll mentioned in the tutorial. My apologies.